# OnClick Javascript doesn't seem to be working properly

Tags: javascript, onclick

I'm doing a project that involves a console-like panel. I've looked around on Google, but I can't solve this problem! I got the load() working, but the click() isn't.

```
<html>

<head>
<script type="text/JavaScript">
function load()
{
  document.getElementById("display").innerHTML="Hello!";
}

function click()
{
  alert("Clicked");
}
</script>
</head>

<body style="background-color:red;" onload="load()">
<div id="display" style="position:absolute; right:0px; left:0px; bottom:0px; width:100%; height:87%; background-color:white;"></div>
<div style="position:absolute; left:0px; width:10%;">
<b>Input:</b>
<input id="text" maxlength=50 />
<input type="button" onclick="click()" value="OK" />
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Help if you can, please! Thanks. :)

Comment: And your problem is...? "Not working" isn't particularly useful diagnostic information. You don't call your doctor and say "I'm sick", then hang up the phone.

Comment: On top are you missing <html> tag?

Comment: @ghostmancer, thanks for updating with html tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just rename your `click` function to something else, e.g. `myclick` and it will work :)

It happens because calling `click()` you trigger the click event again but not your function.

**Check it here**: http://jsfiddle.net/rHyZ7/

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue when naming my function clear()

changing the function name fixed the issue